# MongoExport for field name where field name is not null

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have tried running the shell command:

```
mongoexport -d=local_db -c=ColName -q= '{ "FieldName":{"$ne":"null"}}' --out=NameofJson.json --jsonArray
```

But I return the error:

```
too many positional arguments:  ['{ FieldName:{$ne:null}}']
```

What is the correct Syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the extra whitespace after `-q`:

```
-d=local_db -c=ColName -q='{ "FieldName":{"$ne":"null"}}' --out=NameofJson.json --jsonArray
```

Comment: This didn't work for me? Not sure if you were able to give it a go.

Error:
`too many positional arguments: [FieldName:{$ne:null}}']`

Comment: I actually copied your example into my command line (linux), hit return, got the Error, removed the whitespace, then tried again and it worked.

Comment: Maybe its something to do with windows then, it seems to work if I do a really basic query. This seems to run but doesn't produce what I want: 

```
mongoexport -d=local_db -c=ColName -q="{ 'FieldName':{'$ne':'null'}}" --out=NameofJson.json --jsonArray
```

Comment: Yes.  It's the WIndows command.exe quoting rules.   You have to do "something" with the single and double quotes.   I have little experience with command.exe quoting rules.

Comment: Yeah I managed to get it, thank you for your help. Will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing this in Linux please see Buzz Moschetti's answer. In windows the command was:

```
mongoexport -d=local_db -c=ColName -q="{ 'FieldName':{'$ne':null}}" --out=NameofJson.json --jsonArray
```